# Making Tests Independent of Database Changes

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, integration-testing, test-data, database-testing

I am currently testing a web application with Cypress, and I have multiple databases for this application. However, I encounter test failures when switching between databases. Is there a solution to make my Cypress tests independent of database changes? I appreciate any insights or alternative approaches, even if they involve using a different tool than Cypress.

I've attempted to address the issue by modifying the test data each time I switch the database

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.